# Does a per-site-meta unaccepted answer reflect onto my accept rate?

Tags: support

If reputation and badges never carry over from a site's meta to the site itself, does the accept rate?

Comment: As far as I know, if one answer of yours on meta is flagged as spam, then your reputation on the main site is influenced, when there are enough users that flag it as spam.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't.